# Tetrad formalism

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

What is the current scope of doing research in tetrad formalism to understand gravity? What is the material, book I should refer for doing research on it?

Comment: Haven't really read it, but Alexander Hamilton's got a textbook on [GR, BH & Cosmology](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-General-Relativity-Black-Cosmology/dp/0199666466) (with a preprint version floating around online--not sure the difference between preprint and published versions) that covers tetrad formalism. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

The tetrad formalism is simply a recasting of general relativity in terms of different variables; there is a geometric meaning to it, but it's not a new theory or an extension.

It is very useful for when working with gravity with fermions, and thus a useful component in supergravity. Even in general relatively alone it is handy to quickly calculate curvature forms and work in greater generality doing curvature calculations.

*Supergravity* by Freedman and Van Proeyen provides an introduction to the framework with an application to supergravity in mind.

The first few chapters of *Exact Solutions to Einstein's Field Equations* also provides an overview of differential geometry with the tetrad formalism.